# FIrebase auth: check if user exist before create new one with signInWithPopup()

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I want to add the ability for already registered users to log in using Facebook. I'm using `signInWithPopup` method with `FacebookAuthProvider` for this. But when user with the same email does not exist, Firebase creating the new user - what I don't need.

Can I somehow cancel the creation of a new user after successful login via Facebook, if I do not have a user with the same Email?

Comment: I solved this issue by first authenticating the user, then since they are authenticated you can check if that user exists in your database before letting them continue to account creation. If the user already exists, reroute them to their profile, if they don't, then continue to the new profile creation

Comment: @Amin but what if he cancel the registration and didn't create an account with email? You will have an empty user registered with Facebook

Answer (score 2):

`signInWithPopup` will return a `UserCredential` object if everything went right. If you want, you can check the `_tokenResponse` property of the object, which itself is another object containing a property called `isNewUser`. As you might have guessed this property returns whether the currently signed-in user is a new user or not. If it's a new user you can delete the user via `firebase.auth.currentUser().delete()`, otherwise it's not a new user and you can handle it accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to delete the newly created user like so:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
user.delete().catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);       
});
```

You can check this out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user